# Change HTML5 Audio Title on iOS Devices

Tags: ios, html, audio, media-player

While playing back HTML5 Audio the controls integrate with the system's music player (for example when locking the device). However, the title of the audio is shown as the URL where it is stored.

Is there any way to set the title so that it shows for example the name and artist?

I cannot find any information on this. Neither on Apple's developer page nor elsewhere.

Comment: Did @Kevinosaurio answer worked for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
<audio src="" type="" controls title="Your title"></audio>
```